# Error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '=' toke

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, arduino

Not too sure why I am getting an error here. Working with an Arduino, and it's compiler. If anyone can help clear this up for me that would be greatly appreciated.

```
unsigned char topState, leftState, rightState, fwdState, bwdState;
topState = leftState = rightState = fwdState = bwdState = 1;
```

> Error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '=' token

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Are you trying to do those assignments outside of a function context? That's not going to work.

Comment: yes, I am declaring it globally. Should I declare it and then initialize inside the function?

Comment: Or initialize at declaration time, yes.

Comment: That error message make sense only for C++, not C.

Comment: @KeithThompson, yeah, OP is using C++, he just doesn't know it. All that arduino stuff is in in C++. I'll fix the tags now.

Comment: Well, I was trying to avoid having to write 5 lines saying the same thing. @KeithThompson just using the arduino compiler...

Comment: Well.. I guess it's good to know I'm working with C++ now instead of C. Don't know why I thought Arduino is C..

Comment: So actually, quick google search... (http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/816/c-vs-the-arduino-language - for those interested) Arduino can be written with C or C++ @CarlNorum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have an assignment statements outside of a function/method context. Either initialize properly:

```
unsigned char topState = 1, leftState = 1, rightState = 1, fwdState = 1, bwdState = 1;
```

Or write/call an initialization function someplace.